# Isolate Resource Group and Apply Tags

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm trying to apply a set of tags to a particluar resource group, however it seems to target all the vms in the subscription. I'm sure I'm doing something silly, but been here for hours and now my heads starting to hurt.

The code I have is below.

Basically grab a resource group and within that resource group tag each vm.

```
$rgs = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | where {$_.ResourceGroupName -like 'Linux-*'} 
$rgs | Format-Table
foreach ($VMObjects in $rgs) 
{

        $VMObjects = Get-AzureRmVM 
            ForEach($vmobject in $vmobjects)
        {
        $tags2 =$VMObject.tags
        $tags2 += @{ShutdownSchedule_Mis = "20:00->15:00" }

Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceName $vmobject.Name -ResourceGroupName $vmobject.ResourceGroupName -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -Tag $tags2 -Force -Verbose
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redifining your own variable `$VMObjects`, i dont think that is what you intend to do. You also forgot to scope `Get-AzureRmVm` to a current resource group. I would do it like this.

```
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -like 'Linux-*'} | ForEach-Object {
    $VMObjects = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName
    ForEach ($vmobject in $vmobjects) {
        $tags2 = $VMObject.tags
        $tags2 += @{ShutdownSchedule_Mis = "20:00->15:00" }

        Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceName $vmobject.Name -ResourceGroupName $vmobject.ResourceGroupName -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -Tag $tags2 -Force -Verbose
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh so when I was doing Get-AzureRmVm it was looking at the whole subscription? Thanks that worked a treat .. :)